# Convert figma file to image format

Tags: javascript, reactjs, figma, figma-api

I want to let user upload figma file and diplay those figma files as images in React application.

use case: User can upload his/her design as figma files and display as images

Can i do this task?

Comment: Assume you can, have a go, and the come back with a [mcve] if you run into any issues.

Comment: Just i want to convert figma file to image for display on browser

Comment: That's not a simple task. Please do some research, have a go, and then come back when you have a specific issue.

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to use the API to [authenticate](https://www.figma.com/developers/api#oauth2) the user.
2. Then you need to prompt the user to type in the figma url of his project. Figma projects are not files, but urls.
3. Then you parse the json from the [API response](https://www.figma.com/developers/api#get-files-endpoint) and fetch all top level frames/artboards
4. You need to instruct the user to have an export property added to all top level artboards. Then with the [images API call](https://www.figma.com/developers/api#get-images-endpoint) you fetch the exported image and save it on your server
5. Figma projects usually have multiple artboards so you need to fetch the images of all artboards.

Answer (score 0):

to convert the figma file to images, you need to select the file or layout that you want to convert and then go to top-right corner hover on figma logo,
select files --> export.

then you can check/uncheck the files and click on export.

Comment: The OP want's to do it in a react application.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).